# Arduino: command not found

Tags: arduino-uno, command-line, johnny-five

After installing the Arduino IDE on MacOS (1.8.5), I am trying to run some commands in the terminal to flash the firmware on an Uno R3.

I have successfully connected and uploaded through the GUI, but would like to use the command line for the `johnny-five` API (https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/wiki/Getting-Started).

However, when running

```
arduino --install-library "Firmata,Servo"
```

I get the following error:

> -bash: command not found

How do I install the command line interface?

Comment: simple google search gives this https://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/CommandLine

Comment: I was on that page earlier today. It says the CLI has been available since 1.5, but it isn't bound to anything on the command line on my machine after installing 1.8.5.

Comment: Not really an arduino question, more of a linux one.    Command not found means there is no program "arduino" in your path

Comment: Yes... I thought this community would likely have better knowledge as to what the actual path is...

Comment: Depends on where you installed it...   have you done something like sudo apt-get install arduino

Comment: I ran `sudo npm i arduino --unsafe-perm` on MacOS.

Comment: npm is the Node.JS package manager. It has nothing to do with the Arduino IDE, it just installs a Node package with the name 'arduino'.

Comment: the arduino builder is installed with IDE. you must only ensure that it can be found. try full path for execution. I can't give you details for Mac.

Comment: I can successfully upload with the builder...  What is the Linux path?

Comment: the installation folder of the IDE. it is the 'arduino' file. it starts the IDE if invoked without parameters

Comment: Arduino has a new CLI https://blog.arduino.cc/2018/08/24/announcing-the-arduino-command-line-interface-cli/

Answer (score 3):

Instructions to installing and binding the Arduino CLI can be found at

https://github.com/arduino/arduino-cli#getting-started

Once you install the binary, copy the executable into a directory which is in your PATH environment variable (such as `/usr/local/bin/`).

Note: You may have to rename the binary to `arduino-cli`.